# How can I break only long words in IE?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

In IE this long string '**1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111**' is recognized as a word, so the word break does not happen at all when I resize the IE browser, I know that **word-break:** **break-all** can break the any long string when changing the size of the browser.

But if I change it to break-all, Hello World will be broke at any character, it doesn't make sense, so how can I handle these two strings at the same time, breaking the long string with the same letter(break when resizing the browser) and a normal sentence(when resizing the browser, break it by word).

```
   <div style="word-break: break-word" >
      <p>1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111</p>
      <p>Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World</p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use word-break and overflow-wrap attribute.

```
<style>
    #test {
        word-break: break-all;
        overflow-wrap: break-word;
    }
</style>
<div id="test">
    <p>1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111</p>
    <p>Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World</p>
</div>
```

**EDIT**:
You may set the attribute seperatedly.

```
 <div >
    <p style="word-break: break-all">1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111</p>
    <p style="word-break: break-word">Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World</p>
</div>
```

Comment: In this way, 'Hello Word' may break at any character rather than keeping a completed word

Comment: @HungryBird I've edited the code. It is easy to set the attribute seperatedly to achieve your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Break word is not supported by IE. You can use word wrap instead of that. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break

Also agree with the other answer that says that you can apply styles individually.